# No WIFI Access in Ubuntu Gnome 14.04

Tags: wireless, iwlwifi, wifi-hardware-switch, wifi-direct, madwifi

I've Ubuntu Gnome 14.04 installed on HP Pavilion N013TX. I am not able to use wifi on my laptop. There's only wired connection in the network setting. My ubuntu software is up to date. I've also installed the additional drivers. What should I do to enable wifi in ubuntu?

Comment: Can you add `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net; rfkill list all` to your question

Comment: Please [run the WiFi diagnostics](/a/425205/175814) and [edit] your question to include a link to the result.

Answer (score 1):

Try going to **System settings** -> **Software & updates** -> **Additional drivers**

It will take a little time while it searches for drivers. In my case, I needed to install a proprietary Broadcom driver. I hope this helps.